# Dotted CSS border cuts off to a half dot

Tags: html, css, wordpress, border

See dotted borders here, this seems to only happen in firefox. The dotted border in general looks horrible in chrome.

That little last dot is always cut in half! It's really annoying. Any fix?

Comment: I think it depends on the div size?

Comment: Can we see your CSS and HTML? Also is the border and image or are you using CSS to create it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its hard to say what it is without seeing any code. But I bet it is because your container is `overflow:hidden`; and your element with the dotted border is wider than it's container.

Comment: This explains the problem, but it does not appear to address the question.

Comment: How does it not address the question? In my opinion the question is vague and by looking at the image with no code provided it appears to be a CSS issue.

Comment: Sorry, I tried adding the URL but it said it wasn't valid and wouldn't let me. (It's an IP address test site, I guess it looks sketchy) - but I set a width to the element and its perfect now. Thanks!

Comment: No problem.. I am glad I was able to help.